# Why does unsafe { x } == y not compile?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I'm getting some compile errors in something I believe it should work:

```
fn function() -> bool {
    unsafe { 1 } == 1
}
```

```
error: expected expression, found `==`
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |     unsafe { 1 } == 1
  |                  ^^ expected expression

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:14
  |
9 |     unsafe { 1 } == 1
  |              ^ expected `()`, found integer

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `testcon` due to 2 previous errors
```

I get that this is kind of useless, but that `1` is really a unsafe function.
But then this works just fine.

```
fn function() -> bool {
    let var = unsafe { 1 };
    var == 1
}
```

I get that maybe both will be optimized to be exactly the same but I'm curious about the why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `unsafe` is a kind of block expression, so when it appears at the beginning of a statement we can omit the semicolon at the end, but this means it is parsed as a whole statement and we cannot use it as part of an expression. [This is mentioned in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#expression-statements):

> An expression that consists of only a [block expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) or control flow expression, if used in a context where a statement is permitted, can omit the trailing semicolon. This can cause an ambiguity between it being parsed as a standalone statement and as a part of another expression; in this case, it is parsed as a statement.

The fix is to wrap it in parentheses:

```rust
fn function() -> bool {
    (unsafe { 1 }) == 1
}
```

Comment: In my tests adding explicit `return` also helped.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Because that makes it not the start of the statement.