Why is () expected here?
Consider these two function definitions in Rust:
fn f() -> i32 {
  7 - { let b=9; b }
}

fn g() -> i32 {
  { let a=7; a } - { let b=9; b }
}

Function f is perfectly fine, but function g gives a compile error:
> 6 |   { let a=7; a } - { let b=9; b }
    |              ^ expected `()`, found integer

Can someone please explain? I would think { let a=7; a } is exactly the same as 7?

As the second duplicate link (“Why does unsafe { x } == y not compile?”) says, you can fix it by putting parentheses around the blocks like ({ let a=7 ... 9; b}).

I voted to reopen - it is not 100% clear to me why the other questions solve the same problem. The answer may be the same without questions being duplicates

The second duplicate link was https://stackoverflow.com/a/76297007/707111, which is much better than either of the current answers here.

It gets possibly worse when you compare 7 - { let b=9; b } to { let b=9; b } - 7. The first one will compile, the second won't.

but -- { let a=7; a } - 9 will

@Simson If the answer is the same, it is a duplicate, even if the questions are not the same (but in this case they really are). Duplicates are all about the ability to answer this question from the answer given to another.

@ChayimFriedman 75% - the other question is a duplicate of this, but not the other way around - it had the element of the unsafe which was unrelated to the actual problem for both questions it turns out.

@Simson Indeed, and because it's not relevant, it is a duplicate. Maybe this question could become a better target - but it came later.

yes that is the problem with current duplicate system.

@Simson Generally, we allow closing questions as duplicates of questions that came later, but that question already has a good answer.

I have re-closed. The answer in the dupe addresses the properties of blocks / block expressions, includes a supporting authoritative reference, and provides a succinct workaround that can trivially be applied to this question. The unsafe difference is moot.

Because it would cause syntax ambiguity two block expressions cannot be used as operands by them self, combining them with a constant or encapsulating in () will remove this ambiguity and make them computeable.
fn f() -> i32 {
  7 - { let b=9; b }
}
 
 
fn g() -> i32 {
  ({ let a:i32=7; a }) - { let b: i32=9; b }
}

fn g1() -> i32{
  let x = { let a: i32=7; a };
  x - { let b: i32=9; b }
}

fn g2() -> i32 {
    --{ let a:i32=7; a } - { let b: i32=9; b }

  }


The "for some reason" is the interesting part. It almost seems like some form of precedence, that the block expressions are not evaluated before the subtraction operator, unless one side forces this (like the lone 7 in the question).

yes I'm not answer the why but addresses how to get rid of the problem

This is the forsome reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76296991/why-does-unsafe-x-y-not-compile/76297007#76297007 just ignore the unsafe part which is the confufesement
